# How can we get notified if the phone has got internet access?

Tags: android

Is there a broadcast receiver or some kind of setting that we can listen/monitor to get notified if the internet/network has been connected.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Listen for [CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)

This looks like good [sample code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/frameworks/base/core/java/android/net/NetworkConnectivityListener.java).  Here is a snippet:

```
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```